# Is US Driver's license valid in Europe for Indian Citizens?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, driving-licenses, us-residents

I am an Indian citizen, living in US on a work visa and hold a valid US drivers license. I plan to visit Netherlands, Belgium and France and drive in those countries round trip starting from Amsterdam. I was searching for this information but did not find a proper resource.

Do Indian passport holders with US drivers license require a International Driving Permit to drive in these countries ? As a Indian citizen, can I obtain IDP from US?

Comment: Your citizenship is irrelevant. If a US driver's license is valid, it is valid for everyone.

Answer (score 5):

Here's what the national road traffic agency (Dutch: Rijksdienst voor het Wegverkeer) [has to say](https://www.rdw.nl/englishinformation/Paginas/Using-a-foreign-driving-licence-after-becoming-a-resident-of-the-Netherlands.aspx?path=Portal/Information%20in%20English/Driving%20licence):

> A tourist in the Netherlands?
>
> Are you not settling in the Netherlands, but you are here as a tourist? In that case, you can drive on the Dutch roads using your foreign driving licence.

Comment: That is not whole truth. In next part there is written: "Has your driving licence been issued in a country outside of the EU/EFTA? In that case, your driving licence categories must comply with the Vienna Convention (categories A, B, C, D, E). If your driving licence does not comply with this, you are advised to have an international driving licence apart from your foreign driving licence. " Category system in US is different so it would be better to have IDP.

Comment: On [tripadvisor](https://www.tripadvisor.ca/ShowTopic-g188590-i60-k8380540-U_S_driver_s_license_in_the_Netherlands-Amsterdam_North_Holland_Province.html) "ive rented cars for months on end and driven all around the NL..my Texas license was all i needed." [USA Today](http://traveltips.usatoday.com/rent-car-holland-20283.html) "Tourists can usually use their U.S. license for driving in Holland."

Answer (score 2):

Update:

I got IDP from US. Easy to get but make sure to carry photo of correct size as it needs to fit in the box of IDP.

Rented round trip from Belgium and I was not asked for IDP.